# Define metisMenu in Webpack using angular

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

I have created project using 'jhipster' and it is `Angular 4` project. It is using `Webpack` and 'yarn'. I installed `metisMenu` for my requirement, it is there in `package.json` file. I defined `metisMenu` in `vendor.ts` and also in 'webpack' but it is showing error `jQuery(...).metisMenu is not a function`.

I am using `Webpack` for first time. What is the exact way to define it in `Webpack` ?

Comment: Hi, could you please share a working code example? I'm actually trying to achieve the same. ta

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek, yup sure. I will share code with you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imported `metisMenu` directly in required `Component` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jeeten Parmar I was able to solve this using the following code in my component where I was referencing it:

```
import 'metismenu';
...

// you can call this inside ngAfterViewInit() in your component
jQuery('#side-menu').metisMenu();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you used angular cli with angular >2 -> 4, you can declared in .angular-cli.json like this :

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js"
        [... others jquery plugin ...]
],
```

And in your component, you declare jquery like this :

```
declare let $: any;
```

You must use ngAfterViewInit for waiting the "dom ready" event. Finaly, you have a component like this :

```
import {Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

declare let $: any;

@Component({ 
    [...]
    ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.menuElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#side-menu');
         (<any>$(this.menuElement)).metisMenu();
    }
```

be careful, if you import jquery like this :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

`$` is a new instance of jquery so MetisMenu will not be implemented inside and jquery object is replaced by the new instance in global

Enjoy :)

Comment: You've a typo in the last line: *remplaced*.